# Update RLMObject is Swift/IOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to update an existing instance of an RLMObject in Realm.

I cant find the method to do it..

Please give me an example.

I've can save and Delete Objects, but cannot figure out how to update an object using:

```
//Find Existing 
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "formname = %@",formname)
var localTypes = FormTypeLocal.objectsWithPredicate(predicate)
if (localTypes.count == 1 ){
var existingForm : FormTypeLocal = localTypes[0] as FormTypeLocal     
existingForm.customProp = "newVal"
//Now I need to update?????

let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
//
// Add to the Realm inside a transaction
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addObject(newForm)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
//Delete
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.deleteObject(newForm)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have tried so far and/or where you have looked for information so far, so people can see what you have tried.

Comment: @mc110: Added what I have done sofar..

Comment: I figured it out...
In Realm, if you update your RLMObject's props, it is immediately persisted... All don in a transaction to keep it atomic:

    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    fm.formdescription = formdescription
    fm.updatedAt = updatedAt
    fm.objectId = objectId
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to make sure your updates are done in a write transaction.

With Realm, as long as you modify/update Realm objects in a write transaction, those changes will be persisted. For example:

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
// Find objects
var localTypes = FormTypeLocal.objectsWhere("formname = \(formname)")
// Update one of those objects
var existingForm = localTypes[0] as FormTypeLocal
existingForm.customProp = "newVal"
// Wrap up transaction
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

We're working on our Swift interface to support generics, so the `as FormTypeLocal` won't be necessary in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much... On a side note: what happens if I do the update without the write transaction? Are the updates lost?

Comment: I love the simplicity of Realm, but I have a repository design where I persist objects by passing the instances into the repo, which in turn creates or updates the object in the data store. I have a couple of different implementations (fake, file etc.), where Realm is used for db persistency. Now, this beginWriteTransaction requirement (though I completely understand why) puts me in a tight spot, since I cannot modify objects and then pass them into the repo. Going Realm would, if I'm not mistaken, require changing my app at all places where I modify my objs, by adding a "begin" step, right?